# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitableview

My application is crushing when i come in this controller by the error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
so i have a problem with the tableView, the class is this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import Social
import AVFoundation


private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"

extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}



class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var type: String

    }


    var previuosViewTappedButtonsArray = [String]()
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var category : QCategoryy?
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0
    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = category?.name

}


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        rows = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
        insertRowsMode3()
        category?.markView()

}




    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        rows = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
        insertRowsMode3()
    }






    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }

        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
        NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)
    }



    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)
            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }















    func insertRowsMode2() {

        for i in 0..<places.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: places[i])
        }

    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:QPlace) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
      tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }



    func insertRowsMode3() {

        rows = 0

        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }




    func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }





    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }





    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return  places.count    /*  rows   */
    }



    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell


        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }



        /*  let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.myImage.image = user.images
        cell.myLabel.text = user.name
        cell.myTypeLabel.text = user.type   */

        return (cell)
    }




     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    })

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }

    }









    func didReceiveUserLocation(_ userLocation:CLLocation) {
        currentLocation = userLocation.coordinate

        loadPlaces(true)
    }

















    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" && sender is IndexPath {


            let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass
            dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
            dvc.places = places
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation





            /*  guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

            let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

            if let user = sender as? User {
            */

            }
        }




    @IBAction func IndTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



































    @IBAction func socialShare(_ sender: Any) {


        //Alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "First share!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        //First action
        let actionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style: .default) { (action) in

            //Checking if user is connected to Facebook
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            {
                let post = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)!

                post.setInitialText("First")
                post.add(UIImage(named: "uround logo.png"))

                self.present(post, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {self.showAlert(service: "Facebook")}

        }

        let actionThree = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        //Add action to action sheet
        alert.addAction(actionOne)

        alert.addAction(actionThree)

        //Present alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    func showAlert(service:String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You are not connected to \(service)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }









}





extension CourseClass2: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        didReceiveUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
        errorGettingCurrentLocation(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            errorGettingCurrentLocation("Location access denied")
        }
    }

    func errorGettingCurrentLocation(_ errorMessage:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

adding a breakpoint i saw that the crush is in this func:

```
 func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < places.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }
```

exactly at this line:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
```

i don't know how i have to modify these functions to solve the problem, i already looked around to other questions but not find something useful.
other classes that work with this UIViewController are:

```
struct QCategoryy {
    var name:String
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension QCategoryy: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.name = value
    }
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(name: value)
    }
}
```

and

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"
private let nameKey = "name"
private let openingHoursKey = "opening_hours"
private let openNowKey = "open_now"
private let vicinityKey = "vicinity"
private let typesKey = "types"
private let photosKey = "photos"


class QPlace: NSObject  {

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var name: String?
    var photos: [QPhoto]?
    var vicinity: String?
    var isOpen: Bool?
    var types: [String]?

    init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {
        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }

        // name
        name = placeInfo[nameKey] as? String

        // opening hours
        if let oh = placeInfo[openingHoursKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let on = oh[openNowKey] as? Bool {
                isOpen = on
            }
        }

        // vicinity
        vicinity = placeInfo[vicinityKey] as? String

        // types
        types = placeInfo[typesKey] as? [String]

        // photos
        photos = [QPhoto]()
        if let ps = placeInfo[photosKey] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for p in ps {
                photos?.append(QPhoto.init(photoInfo: p))
            }
        }
    }

    func getDescription() -> String {

        var s : [String] = []

        if let name = name {
            s.append("Name: \(name)")
        }

        if let vicinity = vicinity {
            s.append("Vicinity: \(vicinity)")
        }

        if let types = types {
            s.append("Types: \(types.joined(separator: ", "))")
        }

        if let isOpen = isOpen {
            s.append(isOpen ? "OPEN NOW" : "CLOSED NOW")
        }

        return s.joined(separator: "\n")
    }

    func heightForComment(_ font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let desc = getDescription()
        let rect = NSString(string: desc).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first update your `UITableViewDataSource`, and then insert rows.

The order of business when inserting rows:
1. Make sure `numberOfRowsInSection` returns new, increased value
2. Make sure `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can provide the data for the cell at new index path
3. Actually insert rows in table view